# DOM Creation from Array: <P> Only Added to First Div, not each

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create HTML and populate it with text from an array.

When I `appendChild` `<p>` by ID (to `div1Id`), the text is ONLY added to the first div (See below). I'm trying to get one `<p>` per `div1Id`.

You can see all of my attempts [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/nateomardavis/vnre62q8/11/) (most recent at the top).

What am I doing wrong?

**IMPROPERLY FORMATTED**
[image]
[image]

**EXPECTED OUTCOME**

```
<h1>text</h1>
<div id='div1Id'>
  <p>text</p>
</div>
<h1>text from array index 0</h1>
<div id='div1Id'>
  <p>text from array index 1</p>
</div>
<h1>
```

**CURRENT ATTEMPT**

```
    $(function() {
       google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(buildH1)
         .ageGroup();
     });

     $(function() {
       google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(buildDiv)
         .division();
     });

     //ATTEMPT 4
     //only works for first div1 (all array values written to one div instead of one per div).
     function buildH1(ageGroupArray) {
       var mainDiv = document.getElementById('accordion');

       ageGroupArray.forEach(function(rowData) {
         var h1 = document.createElement('h1');
         var div1 = document.createElement('div');
         var div1Id = div1.setAttribute('id', 'div1Id');

         h1.appendChild(document.createTextNode(rowData));
         mainDiv.appendChild(h1);
         mainDiv.appendChild(div1);
       });
       document.body.appendChild(mainDiv);
     }

     function buildDiv(divisionArray) {
       var mainDiv = document.getElementById('accordion');
       var getDiv1 = document.getElementById('div1Id');

       divisionArray.forEach(function(cellData) {
         var p = document.createElement('p');
         p.appendChild(document.createTextNode(cellData));
         getDiv1.appendChild(p);
       });
       document.body.appendChild(mainDiv);


       $(document).ready(function() {
         $(function() {
           $("#accordion").accordion({
             collapsible: true
           });
         })
       })
     }
```

Comment: Why mixing DOM and jQuery. It is very confusing and needless.

Comment: great thanks for the help

Comment: `var $acc=$("#"); $(".divClass").each(function(cellData) {
         var $p = $("<p/>").text(cellData).appendTo($acc);
});`

Comment: That didn't work for me either. How would I do it with javascript alone? To answer your earlier question, I'm using Jquery UI as part of the overall project. To get it to render at all, I needed to include it there. If you have a better way I'm happy to hear it. As for my question, You see my comments on the answer below and what I tried here: http://jsfiddle.net/nateomardavis/du5m8fLc/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Id attribute is meant to be unique, not reused for multiple elements.

As such the selector `GetElementById` is going to return a single element.

Use a different selector like `GetElementsByClassName` to get a collection of attributes with a matching `class` attribute.

Additionally, since you are using jQuery already I would recommend you make your life easier using the library instead of the built-in browser selectors.

Using jQuery:

```js
var ageGroup = ["Group 18-25", "Group 25-30"];
var division = ["Group 1 Cell Text", "Group 1 Cell Text"];

$(document).ready(function() {

    $(ageGroup).each(function(i, e) {
      $('#accordion')
       .append($("<h1>").text(e))
       .append($("<div>").addClass("div1class"));
    });
    
    $(division).each(function(i, e) {
      $($('.div1class')[i])
       .append($("<p>").text(e));
    });
    
    $("#accordion").accordion({
      collapsible: true
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div id='accordion'></div>
```

Or using your current code.

```js
var ageGroup = ["Group 18-25", "Group 25-30"];
var division = ["Group 1 Cell Text", "Group 1 Cell Text"];

function buildH1(ageGroupArray) {
  var mainDiv = document.getElementById('accordion');
  ageGroupArray.forEach(function(rowData) {
    var h1 = document.createElement('h1');
    var div1 = document.createElement('div');
    var div1Id = div1.setAttribute('class', 'div1class');

    h1.appendChild(document.createTextNode(rowData));
    mainDiv.appendChild(h1);
    mainDiv.appendChild(div1);
  });
  document.body.appendChild(mainDiv);
}

function buildDiv(divisionArray) {
  var mainDiv = document.getElementById('accordion');
  var getDiv1 = document.getElementsByClassName('div1class');

  $(divisionArray).each(function(i, cellData) {
    var p = document.createElement('p');
    p.appendChild(document.createTextNode(cellData));
    getDiv1[i].appendChild(p);
  });
  document.body.appendChild(mainDiv);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(function() {
    buildH1(ageGroup);
    buildDiv(division);
    $("#accordion").accordion({
      collapsible: true
    });

  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div id='accordion'></div>
```

Comment: After changing the attribute to`class`, I end up with a new error `Uncaught TypeError: getDiv1.appendChild is not a function` When I change it to ` var getDiv1 = document.getElementsByClassName('div1class')[0];` the result is exactly the same as my original problem.

Comment: I tried wrapping in a for loop but that didn't work for me either. http://jsfiddle.net/nateomardavis/du5m8fLc/2/

Comment: See the example snippets I added.

Comment: Awesome. I was able to make the second one work by putting the accordion function inside the `buildDiv` function. I couldn't make the former work because my array is made elsewhere `google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(buildH1).ageGroup();` Thanks again!